# Java Guava splitter do not break the word

Tags: java, guava

It`s possible to not break word when split with java guava spliter?

I have this sample:

```
var String msg = "My name is Fabio and I have a dog";

Splitter.fixedLength(5).split(msg).forEach(item -> {
            System.out.println(item);
        });
```

this will print:

```
My na

me is

 Fabi

o and

 I ha

ve a 

dog
```

But I want that he dont break my word

Just like this:

```
My naME

is Fabio

and I have

a dog
```

Bu I dont have the control the text, I only want to keep the last word for everty split

Answer (score 0):

The method call `fixedLength(5)` will split the text every 5 characters, which is why your words are being broken into two pieces, so you can't use this method for your problem. One thing you could do is to use a regular expression as a delimiter to split the string every whitespace, and use a loop to format the output.

```
ArrayList<String> items = Splitter.onPattern("\\s+").splitToList(msg)
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
     System.out.print(items.get(i) + " ");
     if ((i+1) % 2 == 0) {
          System.out.println();
     }
}
```

This sort of logic should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words and build the lines as you iterate them:

```
final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : Splitter.on(' ').split(msg)) {
    if (builder.length() == 0) {
        builder.append(word);
    } else if (builder.length() <= 5) {
        builder.append(' ').append(word);
    } else {
        lines.add(builder.toString());
        builder.setLength(0);
        builder.append(word);
    }
}
if (builder.length() > 0) {
    lines.add(builder.toString());
}
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
My name
is Fabio
and I have
a dog
```